# How to convert the img grid into a gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to convert this image grid into a gallery?

I've tried many times with no success.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 12px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Responsive Image Grid</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/falls2.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/nature.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/mist.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/ocean.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/mountainskies.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/falls2.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/nature.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/mist.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/ocean.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/mountainskies.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg">
    <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for making gallery you have to use javascript and jquery , check the below link  there you can get code and download   http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Dynamic-Nivo-Responsive-Image-slider-with-database

Comment: You could take a look at this: http://idangero.us/swiper/

Comment: anyone know how to connect photo grid code and this code together??<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}

img:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Thumbnail Image</h2>
<p>Click on the image to enlarge it.</p>

<a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
  <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:150px">
</a>

</body>
</html>